# closing windows: ctrl-W vs alt-space C

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, lag

When closing a window (like notepad or Windows Explorer), I've been realizing that when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> there will be a short lag but when I do <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> there will be no lag.

Does anyone know what exactly is the difference between these 2 shortcuts?

Comment: Why aren't you using Alt-F4?  Alt-Space-C will not work with every program, nor will Ctrl-W.

Comment: @MBraedley the F4 key is too far. either Ctrl-W or Alt-Space-C is much much faster with some practice. Alt-Space-C works with every program that i use though..

Comment: except Notepad z

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> is a sequence that uses <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to open the window controls menu<sup>1</sup>, and then <kbd>C</kbd> to select the **Close** option.

Activating the **Close** option in this way is normally the equivalent to using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, and so Windows will issue the process a `WM_CLOSE` signal, telling it to terminate.

As with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, a program can catch and/or ignore this command (often for very good reasons - think of Word's "do you want to save before you quit?" dialog box, for example).

<sup>1. I've just made this name up for it, it probably has a real one somewhere.</sup>

---

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is a shortcut only provided by the program, and the program can choose to handle the shortcut in whatever way it sees fit.

This involves no action by the operating system.

Comment: Actually, I was somewhat mistaken in my previous comment above.  Pressing space while holding Alt will work it every program (with some very specific exceptions that I can't name right now).  However, using Alt, then space, then C will not work with all programs.

Comment: @MBraedley, yes you're right. Using Alt+Space together is much more reliable at opening the window controls menu (as I'm calling it). Have now edited the answer to use than instead, thanks.